# NextJS getServerSession(authOptions) returns null after declaring NEXTAUTH_URL and NEXTAUTH_SECRET

Tags: reactjs, typescript, prisma, next-auth, next.js13

I am trying to get an OAuth with the Google provider to work with my Next.js 13 web app. Currently I have an error where the getServerSession(authOptions) returns null. I have looked at other solutions (like including a NEXTAUTH_URL and NEXTAUTH_SECRET in .env file. Also tried NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL) and implement them, however, I keep getting null back.

The redirect to the Google sign in page works with no issues, however, in the redirect to the '/dashboard' page, something goes wrong. As I have a check to see if a user/session is present, I keep getting the 404 not found error.

My env:

```
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=randomletters
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

(dashboard)/dashboard/page.tsx:

```
import { FC } from "react"

import ApiDashboard from "@/components/ApiDashboard"
import RequestApiKey from "@/components/RequestApiKey"
// import { authOptions } from "@/lib/auth"
import { db } from "@/lib/db"
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth"

import type { Metadata } from "next"
import { notFound } from "next/navigation"
import { authOptions } from "@/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]"

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: "Similarity API | Dashboard",
    description: "Free and open-source text smilarity API",
}

const page = async () => {
    const user = await getServerSession(authOptions) //<-- this is null 
    if (!user) return notFound() //<-- returns 404 because of this

    const apiKey = await db.apiKey.findFirst({
        where: { userId: user.user.id, enabled: true },
    })
    return (
        <div className="mx-auto mt-16 max-w-7xl">
            {user ? <ApiDashboard /> : <RequestApiKey />}
        </div>
    )
}

export default page
```

Navbar:

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import Link from "next/link"
import { FC } from "react"
import { buttonVariants } from "@/ui/Button"
import SignInButton from "@/components/ui/SignInButton"
import SignOutButton from "@/components/ui/SignOutButton"
import ThemeToggle from "./ThemeToggle"
import { authOptions } from "@/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]"

const Navbar = async () => {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions) //<-- null as well 
    return ( some stuff )
```

[...nextauth].ts:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"

import { db } from "@/lib/db"
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"

function getGoogleCredentials(): { clientId: string; clientSecret: string } {
    const clientId = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    const clientSecret = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
    if (!clientId || clientId.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("Missing GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID")
    }

    if (!clientSecret || clientSecret.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("Missing GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET")
    }

    return { clientId, clientSecret }
}

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login",
    },
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: getGoogleCredentials().clientId,
            clientSecret: getGoogleCredentials().clientSecret,
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({ token, session }) {
            if (token) {
                session.user.id = token.id
                session.user.name = token.name
                session.user.email = token.email
                session.user.image = token.picture
            }

            return session
        },
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            const dbUser = await db.user.findFirst({
                where: {
                    email: token.email,
                },
            })

            if (!dbUser) {
                token.id = user!.id
                return token
            }

            return {
                id: dbUser.id,
                name: dbUser.name,
                email: dbUser.email,
                picture: dbUser.image,
            }
        },
        async redirect() {
            return "/dashboard"
        },
    },
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

If anyone has found a solution, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work in server components though it may work in route handler. I don't think next-auth is working quite right with the new app router of nextJS yet.

Comment: Any new developments here?

Answer (score 0):

In the Nextjs 13 server components, cookies do not pass to the API routes by default. The workaround I did was when you send the request you can pass the headers along with the request as below. This implementation worked for me.

```
import { headers } from "next/headers";

const res = await fetch(ENDPOINT, {
  method: "GET",
  cache: "no-cache",
  headers: headers(),
});
```